# Navigation Left bar button item with back button

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, swift3, uinavigationitem

I want to add left bar button item in `navaigationBar`.
I have back button sign (do not have any text) in left side and when I add `leftBarButtonItem` then I can not see the back button.

How can I solve this problem.

This is my code:

```
let phonePhoto = UIButton()
phonePhoto.setImage(UIImage(named: "navigationPhone"), for: UIControlState())
phonePhoto.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
phonePhoto.addTarget(self, action: #selector(userEdit), for: .touchUpInside)

let userPhone = UIBarButtonItem()
userPhone.customView = phonePhoto

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = userPhone
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The presence of custom left bar button items causes the back button to be removed in favor of the custom items. Set `navigationItem` property `leftItemsSupplementBackButton` to `true` will display back button also with your custom left bar item.

```
self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
```

Check [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624933-leftitemssupplementbackbutton) on `leftItemsSupplementBackButton` for more details.